# Linked Servers in SQL Database Managed Instance

Tags: linked-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

In a SQL Server Managed Instance I have 2 databases (for security reasons both databases have different logins). I need the possibility to allow one database to look into the other one. In a local SQL Server I was able to create a Linked Server to realize this. But this seems not to work using the Managed Instance.
Can someone give some hints how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed Instance supports linked servers (unless if they use MSDTC for some distributed writes). Make sure that you add logins for remote server:

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'PEER',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=N'$(linkedServerUsername)', @rmtpassword='$(linkedServerPassword)';
```

If it still doesn't work put the exact error message. This might be Network security Group blocking the port, VNets that are not peered, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got it. But additionally I had to add the name of the target user in the `sp_addlinkedserver` procedure:`EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'<LINKED SERVER NAME>', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', @provstr=N'Server=<SERVER_DNS_NAME>;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=FalseEncrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Connection Timeout=30;User ID=<TARGET USER>'`